# How to retrieve grouped data from a CSV using PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, csv

I have a `csv` file in this format:

```
Year, Title, Subject
y1,   t1,    s1
y1,   t1,    s2
y1,   t2,    s3
y2,   t3,    s4
```

What is the best way to retrieve all titles group by year? In SQL I know this works:

```
SELECT Title from mytable group by Year
```

And I know in file, this could be done by some (two, I think) nested loops but I wonder if there's a convenient, better way.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you gonna do this once or more times?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to parse the csv and push the year and title into an associative array
with title,subject=>year elements and then do an [associative array sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) based on year.
An alternative to continue using what you know already is to parse with fgetcsv and insert the rows as records in a mysql array and then run your sql.